# Returning a custom exit code from Iced application

Tags: rust, rust-iced

I have a UI application written in iced, which performs various operation. To launch the UI I'm using run() method: `UpdateDriver::run(Settings::default())` and currently this returns the exit code of type `iced::Result` and type of result is `pub type Result = Result<(), Error>;`, but I want the application to return custom exit code of type `u8` based on the operation performed.

*Ex: 0(success), 1(failure), 3(reboot) etc.*

I need help on how to do that.

**Current WorkFlow:**

```
fn launch_ui_mode() -> iced::Result {
    UpdateDriver::run(Settings::default())
}
```

**Expectation:**

```
fn launch_ui_mode() -> u8 {
    UpdateDriver::run(Settings::default())
}
```

**Main Function:**

```
fn main() -> ExitCode {

    let retcode: u8;
    let exec_type = get_execution_mode();

    if exec_mode == UI{ 
        retcode = launch_ui_mode(); //This is iced::result type, I need u8 type
    }
    else{
        retcode = launch_cli_mode();
    }

    return ExitCode::from(retcode);
}
```

My application runs in both CLI and UI mode, for CLI mode I'm directly returning the `u8` type exit code, need to implement that for UI mode too.

So if something like this is not possible, what is the other way to return the exit-code from the UI. Should I add the global variable to store the exit code in UI part of code? Will it be safe?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, did you try `process::exit`? Or you could create your own error enum and use `map_err` on the iced result and map that to an exit code at a higher level depending on your setup. Speaking of which, where are you expecting to process these exit codes? Or are you just trying to capture them in e.g. systemd?

Comment: Are you asking how to [match on an enum](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html) to convert a `iced::Result` into an `u8`?

Comment: So, iced::Result is of type `pub type Result = Result<(), Error>;`, it returns empty() when success, else it returns Error kind in case of err.

I want it to return u8 type value or `pub type Result = Result<u8, Error>;`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with `iced`, but since Rust 1.61 you can return from `main` any type that implements [Termination](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/trait.Termination.html) trait. So you could create some wrapper (new-type pattern) for `iced::Result` and implement `Termination` for it. And then depending on your implementation you can exit with custom exit codes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm already using the std::process::ExitCode in the main, as shown above. I need to get the exit code of type u8, from the iced library